# Stream insert from java: templateSuffix

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I would like to stream data from my java code to a BigQuery table using templateSuffix, but I can't make it work properly. My code:

```
return bigquery.tabledata()
        .insertAll(
                projectId,
                datasetId,
                tableId,
                new TableDataInsertAllRequest()
                        .setTemplateSuffix(templateSuffix)
                        .setRows(singletonList(row))
        ).execute();
```

When I run it with projectId, datasetId, MyTable20160426 and 20160426, I get the error:

```
"message" : "404 Not found: Table projectId:datasetId.MyTable20160426"
```

When I run it with projectId, datasetId, MyTable and 20160426, I get the error:

```
"message" : "404 Not found: Table projectId:datasetId.MyTable"
```

The table MyTable already exists and already is templated on date (I used the bulk upload for GCS) (20160426 is the today date)

How cat I make it work ?

Where should I look to understand what's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: also, where do I provide the schema ? I couldn't find it in the java API for streaming

Answer (score 1):

First, the base table `projectId:datasetId.MyTable` should exist and should already have a schema. Thisis how BigQuery knows how to find the schema of the templated table that gets created.

Second, You should pass `MyTable` and instead of `MyTable20160426` as the table ID in your request.

Third, the existence (or non-existence) of a table is cached. So if you get a "not found" error and then create the table, you'll still get a "not found" error for up to a half hour.

It sounds like you might be able to wait and try again. If this doesn't work, please provide the actual project, dataset, and table ids you're using and e-mail the details to tigani@google.com, and I can help look into what is going on.